# passing base url from command line in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

i am trying to test my angularjs app using protractor.
my conf.js looks like this

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
specs: ['HomePageCtrl_spec.js'],
chromeOnly: true,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true
},
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
},
params : {
    url : 'test'
}};
```

and i am runnig this command on command prompt

```
protractor Conf.js --params.url='https://XXXXX/YYY'
```

in my spec file, in beforeEach function i am able to get the passed url (`console.log((browser.params.url))` is coming correctly), but when i do `browser.get(browser.params.url)`.. it is not working

anyone has idea why this is failing?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Any errors? Thanks.

Comment: i was getting timeout...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Protractor provides it by default. You just have to declare the correct variable.

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
specs: ['HomePageCtrl_spec.js'],
chromeOnly: true,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true
},
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
},
  baseUrl: 'test'
};
```

and then, you run the tests:

```
protractor Conf.js --baseUrl="https://XXXXX/YYY"
```

To use this url within your tests:

```
browser.get(browser.baseUrl)
```