# How to set dynamic URL in cucumber.conf.js file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I have configured cucumber config file. I have defined the baseURL. But now I want to set dynamic URL at run time. How to set the dynamic URL?

For example, Now the base URL is pointing to my localhost. Later on, in test or production environment, the IP address will be changed to a different server. How do I set dynamic URL?

```
//cucumber.conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  directConnect: true,
  specs: ['test/e2e/cucumber/sample.feature'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        //"--headless",
        "--disable-gpu",
        '--disable-extensions',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-web-security'
      ],
    },

  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/dashboard/#/',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,


  // cucumber command line options
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['test/e2e/cucumber/menu.steps.js'],
    tags: [],
    strict: true,
    format: ["pretty"],
    dryRun: false,
    compiler: []
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
  },

  resultJsonOutputFile: './test/e2e/results.json'
}
```

Comment: Hi,


This has nothing to do with CucumberJS directly but with Protractor. You can pass or a command line argument, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114243/passing-base-url-from-command-line-in-protractor) for an explanation.

Comment: @wswebcreation Okay thanks.